# Parsing and Processing Large files

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large CSV file that i need to break into 4 parts and then send data to the database; the problem that I have is that CSV file can be 1GB+ (and their might be more then one at a time) which creates various time delays and memory issues.

I would like some help on how I can improve and speed up the process.

The file that I am test this on has 45000 records; ~10mb file.

Right now I am loading file into array, which is using around 3 times the size of the file, so for 10mb file we are talking 30mb memory; I am hoping to reduce the need for 30mb memory by reading file line by line, yet to look at this one.

Processing part is rather simple, essentially I loop through the array of data.

The last part is saving data to the database, where the main problem at the moment is at, due to time it takes to save data in to the database;

Initially I have tried creating a large string and sending it all into DB, but 22k records need around 2GB of ram memory; even tho this process is rather quick i keep running out of memory.

My current method that I have implemented is adding row at a time, which doesn't need much memory, but to process 45k records may take nearly an hour.

My next step is to look at creating a mysql file with full list of queries and importing all that into MySQL via mysql import function.

It would be great if some one could advice on how I can improve performance of the script further..

---

**Update 1**
Right now I dont load file into memory anymore and process file line by line. Which doesn't take to long to process a large file. It takes seconds to process 500MB data file.

On the import into DB side of things I have two methods in place that I am trying:

1. Using PDO, import statement at a time: take about 1 minutes to process 5MB data file; very slow
2. Using mysql < file.sql, import is quicker, takes about 1 minute to process 10MB data file; which is better but still slow. The trade off is that i need to generate .sql file which can be very large, at the moment 20MB data file will result in a .sql file a size of about 600MB;

At the moment I am considering trying "LOAD DATA INFILE" but I am need to do a work around due to a couple of tables having one to many relationship and i need to have last inserted id.

---

**Update 2**

Load Data Local Infile managed to resolved some hard-drive problems; I also had to use SplFileObject to make file reading easier for me. The file that I create for Load Data Local Infile is still quite big but it's much better than what it was before.

At the moment I am having to perform a loop through the file and store start / end points of where information is at, while doing this I create all the tables except for the one that needs foreign keys. So what I did is:

Table A and Table B have one to many relation: Table A is created at the first loop (the loop through the file) and additionally to that we store parameters for Table B in a cell within Table A.

One the second loop, we loop through Table A and grab data from the cell and create a new set of rows in Table B.

in the first loop I am having to parse parameters for Table B to improve performance of the second loop.

I have quite a few foreach / for statements in the second loop due to which second loop take x4 as long to complete.

Performance at current moment as follows for 10MB file:

- First loop 6 seconds
- Second loop 12 seconds
- Average Total Time 18-20 second

However, performance seem to worsen as file gets larger, 40MB file:

- First loop 30 seconds
- Second loop 60 second
- Average Total Time 90-100 seconds

If I dont parser parameters in the first loop for Table B performance for 10MB:

- First loop 3 seconds
- Second loop 16 seconds
- Average Total Time 19-22 second

Performance for 40MB file is great in the first loop but awful in the second loop.

Without any foreach loops in first and second loop it would take around 3-4 seconds to process 10MB

Example of the foreach loop in the first loop, that organises parameters for Table B :

```
public function parseRawParam($line, $titles) {
        $params = [];

        $line = str_replace("\n", "", $line);
        $rows = explode(",", $line);

        for($row_i = 4; $row_i < count($rows); $row_i++) {
            if(strlen(trim($rows[$row_i])) < 1) {
                break;
            }

            $params[$titles[$row_i]] = $rows[$row_i];
        }

        return $params;
    }
```

$line may have parameters anywhere from 4 and upto 160.

Second loop has a foreach loop that handles insert of params and it is the thing that takes alot of time:

```
public function insertParam($record_id, $params) { 
        $sql = "";
        foreach ($params as $param => $value) {  
            $sql  = '"' . $record_id . '","' . str_replace("'", "\'", trim($param)) . '","' . trim($value) . '";';
        }
        return $sql; 
    }
```

I have been looking at performance between different PHP versions and PHP7 is much faster incomparison to php 5.6, so I am looking to upgrade PHP versions and compering performance.

Comment: research LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Try to chunk it…? It's a space time trade-off. How much space do you have or how much time are you willing to sacrifice. 1 row per query → very slow, 22k rows per query → fast, but huge memory requirements. Optimal solution → somewhere inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

For the database you need to use LOAD DATA INFILE. You should be able to build a text file of rows to bulk insert into the database table in one go if you are doing any data alterations to your CSV data. That should reduce the lock ups for single table row inserts which are costly.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: the problem that i have is csv that file had data for five different tables; two of which have one to many relationship and i need a use of last inserted id

Comment: Are you not asking it to do too much in one hit. Can the problem be broken down where those other inserts are done. A collection of IDs are gathered in one SELECT then stored in an array and looked up against instead of hitting the db for each one? There is always a simpler solution if broken down.

Comment: at the moment one solution that I am considering is using triggers. The tables in question are: records and parameters; 1 record may have many parameters. The plan is to add extra column to the "records" table which will store parameters; when row is inserted trigger will some how grab the "parameters" from the cell and insert new rows into "parameters" table. Another solution, is to loop through the data twice, very much what you have said, first loop creates sql file for "records" table; after load data infile is done we loop again and create file for "parameters"; problem now is disk space